# Como colocar uma DIV no lugar de uma palavra especifica com script?

Tags: javascript, script, div

Quero que onde esteja **texto** fique por exemplo `<div> novo texto </div>`, queria saber se da pra fazer isso.

Resumindo, quero que em todos os lugar do site que tenha a palavra **texto** mude pra uma **DIV** e suma o texto anterior.

> UPDATE

Consegui fazer o que queria com esse código

```
$("p:contains('Esgotado')").replaceWith("<div id='esgotado'>SEM ESTOQUE</div>");
```

Com isso em todos os lugares do site que tem a palavra "Esgotado" dentro de uma tag `<p> Esgotado </p>` muda para `<div id='esgotado'>SEM ESTOQUE</div>`

Comment: `texto_html.replace('texto', '<div> novo texto </div>');`

Comment: deu o erro no console (texto_html is not defined), mudei pro nome que quero substituir que é ESGOTADO e mesmo assim deu erro.

Comment: Você não pode colocar um `<div>` dentro dum parágrafo vai contra as recomendações da *W3C*. Mesmo que os browser hoje suportem esse comportamento nada garante que em uma alteração futura esse comportamento seja abolido e passe a gerar erros de sintaxe. Teste no [validador da *W3C*](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) e [aqui](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) a recomeçadão sobre conteúdo fraseado.

Answer (score -1):

Você deveria utilizar o método replaceWith ao invés de html.

Veja se isto te ajuda:

```
$('p').replaceWith( "<div>" + $('p').text() + "</div>" );
```

Comment: Troquei aqui e funcionou  - $("p:contains('Esgotado')").replaceWith("<div id='esgotado'>SEM ESTOQUE</div>");

Comment: Opa! Foi mal! Esqueci de colocar o ":contains('Esgotado')".  Abraço